# How Can I combine two columns is one dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like this.

```
A  B  C  A2
1  2  3   4
5  6  7   8
```

and I want to combine A and A2.

```
A  B  C
1  2  3
5  6  7
4 
8
```

how can I combine two columns?
Hope for help. Thank you.

Comment: Does this work? `df.A = (df.A).append(df.A2)` . If it works, it might fill the other cells on the neighbouring columns with NaN or zeroes, I am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible directly. But you can do it with a few lines of code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,5],'B':[2,6],'C':[3,7],'A2':[4,8]})

df_A2 = df[['A2']]
df_A2.columns = ['A']
df = pd.concat([df.drop(['A2'],axis=1),df_A2])
```

You will get this if you print `df`:

```
   A    B    C
0  1  2.0  3.0
1  5  6.0  7.0
0  4  NaN  NaN
1  8  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

You could append the last columns after renaming it:

```
df.append(df[['A2']].set_axis(['A'], axis=1)).drop(columns='A2')
```

it gives as expected:

```
   A    B    C
0  1  2.0  3.0
1  5  6.0  7.0
0  4  NaN  NaN
1  8  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

if the index is not important to you:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.concat([df[['A','B','C']], df[['A2']].rename(columns={'A2': 'A'})]).reset_index(drop=True)
```